# Cannot read properties of undefined - reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Please help. I am new to react and I'm trying to toggle an accordion by using state but I'm getting an error on the onClick portion. Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggleAccordion'). I'm confused to what I should do.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
export class Accordion extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isActive: false
        }

        this.toggleAccordion = this.toggleAccordion.bind(this);
        this.renderAccordion = this.renderAccordion.bind(this);
    }

    toggleAccordion = () => {
        this.setState({ isActive: !this.state.isActive})
    }

    renderAccordion = () => 
    {
        const { items } = this.props;
        const { isActive } = this.state;

        const accordionItems = items.map(function(item) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button className={styles.accordion} onClick={this.toggleAccordion()}>
                        {item.title}
                        <span style={{float: "right"}}>{isActive ? '-' : '+'}</span>
                    </button>
                    {isActive && <div className={styles.content} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: item.content}}></div>}
                    <br/><br/>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return (
            {accordionItems}
        )
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                {this.renderAccordion()}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: try `onClick={this.toggleAccordion}`

Comment: I tried but it's the same error :(

Comment: can you share a minimal-reproduceable example on stackblitz or codesandbox? it'll be easier to get you unblocked that way

Answer (score 0):

In React you need to provide a reference to the function in event handlers, instead of calling the function. Try (note the parenthesis) :

```
<button className={styles.accordion} onClick={() => this.toggleAccordion()}>
```

or

```
<button className={styles.accordion} onClick={this.toggleAccordion}>
```

instead of

```
<button className={styles.accordion} onClick={this.toggleAccordion()}>
```

See https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper for more details on how React handle events.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. I've tried this but still getting the same error.